# How to make self-contained or java-bundled JavaFX application package for ARM

Tags: linux, javafx, arm

**Where could I acquire a working copy of compiled JavaFX app bundled with JRE so I could execute this app on ARM linux?**

or

**How can I create my JavaFX app + JRE bundle that would work on ARM Linux**

Best case scenario for me would be to be ableto create copy-paste enabled folder tree or single executable file..

I do understand that this question might be too vague, but I desperately need some help on this. I have spent more than 6 evenings + 2 nights searching how to get a compiled JavaFX application ( .jar file) to run on ARM linux on UDOO (RPi2-like) board.

I have been more of an .NET guy a long time, and now I had to make WPF-like rich UX app that would run on this specific hardware, and I chose JavaFX due to its likeliness to WPF. It does run fine on my desktop PCs but I absolutely can not get it to run on ARM linux.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do this too. Did you get it working? My solution is to package the JAR using tools provided by IntelliJ or any other IDE, include the JRE in a folder within the app, then write a script that invokes the JAR from the included JRE like:

```
lib/jre/bin/java -jar runthis.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried it for two days now but didn't get it to work.
I use maven in combination with the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) to build native installers of an application.

At first I got the error, that the javafx-ant.jar tools are missing:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal build-jar(create-jfxjar) on project foo: 
Execution create-jfxjar of goal build-jar failed: Plugin javafx-maven-plugin or 
one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact 
javafx-packager:javafx-packager:jar:1.8.0 at specified path 
/opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/../lib/ant-javafx.jar
```

Then I found the `ant-javafx.jar` in a windows JDK but then another error was reported that linux is not supported with this one. Ok so I downloaded a linux JDK and used that `ant-javafx.jar`. Now it could build and create a *.deb file **successfully**!

**However** when I started the installer it failed with a message and when checking the log (/var/log/apt/term.log)

Log started: 2021-04-29  00:40:01
dpkg: Error creating archive
/home/pi/Foo/target/jfx/native/foo.deb (--unpack):
package architecture (amd64) does not match system (armhf)

Then I did research and found the following [mailing list entry](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2016-August/019634.html):

> [...] the Java Packager isn’t shipped with any ARM builds that I’m aware of. Currently it is only for X86 Windows, Linux and Mac. [...]

This basically explains it: The packager doesn't work on ARM for now. Maybe we should write the guy to encurage him to add it...

**=> So for now I work with the jar directly.**